# Can I pre-transform images when training a deep learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

If you ever trained a model, you sometimes can see DataLoader (e.g. I am using pytorch Dataloader) could be the bottleneck because everytime you get an training sample from the dataset, the data transformation will be performed on-the-fly. Here I take the **getitem** func of DatasetFolder from `torchvision.datasets` as an example.

```
    path, target = self.samples[index]
    sample = self.loader(path)
    if self.transform is not None:
        sample = self.transform(sample)
    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)

    return sample, target
```

I wonder can we pre-processed the images (e.g. ImageNet) in advance to tensors and save to disk. Then we modify the `__getitem__` function to get these tensors directly from disk. How efficient is this approach? Anyone has tried this solution before?

I think that maybe the loading from disk will burden and likely become a new bottleneck (instead of data transform we have before). Another thing is the size, for example, one ImageNet image takes 74 MB when being saved as tensors using standard transformation:

```py
transforms.Compose([
                transforms.Resize(256),
                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
            ])
```

Comment: maybe try to convert and keep on disk - and create own function/class to get item from disk (without using `DataLoader`)

Comment: typically you can save as ```.npy``` file

Comment: As I mentioned, if I do that, one image of ImageNet takes 74 MB, then It will take 70TB for 1M images, not mentioning that the loading cost (e.g. the npy files and .pt files) from the disk could be expensive

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1)You can cache the Dataset if you have enough memory and use it later. The limitation is you are limited to `0` workers in the first epoch. Something like this.

```
class ImageNetDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, use_cache=False):
        self.cached_data = []
        self.use_cache = use_cache
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if not self.use_cache:
            x = self.data[index] 
            self.cached_data.append(x)
        else:
            x = self.cached_data[index]
        return x
    
    def set_use_cache(self, use_cache):
        if use_cache:
            self.cached_data = torch.stack(self.cached_data)
        else:
            self.cached_data = []
        self.use_cache = use_cache
```

2)Transform the dataset beforehand and save it to disk. You need to write a small code for that separately. And use this folder during training.